# Apex: debugging classes from test

Tags: apex, unit-test

How can I output `System.debug()` lines that exist in the class that I'm testing? I can run the test just fine, but all the `System.debug()` lines are in the class and **not** the test, so when I run the test I get no debugging output. What can I do?

Comment: you need to check debug log.. goto setup- > logs--> debuglogs  check there

Comment: make sure you are not exceeding the debug log size. open your log and check for following message. "Maximum Debug log size reached"

Comment: When you run test class it will show system.debug for your class as well test class in dev console

Comment: Nope, doesn't. Using normal `System.debug(whatever)` in the class, test gets no output. Unless you're right, and my class is broken initially...

Comment: can you post screenshot of dev console ?

Comment: Like, the output? Or of the class and the test class?

Comment: check whether the debug log is expired @CD-RUM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce has changed the traditional way of checking debug logs. Now, we have to set a log level and define a time range for all the transaction logs. So, you should also need to check your Debug Level for your logged-in user from Setup->Logs->Debug Logs. Hope it would help you!!

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend the answer and comments above:

If the tested class is in a managed package, the logs won't show in the Debug Logs. You can only view them through the [LMA app](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/168/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/lma.pdf).